# Is it a scope issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I add a close button to the card. I try this code but the close button seems not working.

```
$('#add-pet').on('click', e => {

    // Grab info from the form
    let $name = $('#pet-name').val();
    let $species = $('#pet-species').val();
    let $notes = $('#pet-notes').val();

    let $newPet = $(
        '<section class="six columns"><div class="card"><p><strong>Name:</strong> ' + $name +
        '</p><p><strong>Species:</strong> ' + $species +
        '</p><p><strong>Notes:</strong> ' + $notes +
        '</p><span class="close">&times;</span></div></section>'
    );

    // Attach the new element to the page
    $('#posted-pets').append($newPet);

});
$('.close').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

However, when I move this code:

```
$('.close').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

right after the `$('#posted-pets').append($newPet);`
Then it works OK.
Why it is like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to make an event for an element which may be appended via jquery, you can try:

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

It works after you appending `span.close` tag. Even if outside the scope

```
$('#add-pet').on('click', /*...*/);
```

**Update:**

You can also try:

```
$('#add-pet').on('click', e => {
    let close_tag = $('<span>').addClass('close');

    // do stuff...

    // set event
    close_tag.on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });

    $('#posted-pets').append(close_tag);

});
```

Comment: Why we need to addClass ('close')? is the <span> already has that class?

Comment: @AiNguyen `$('<span>')` will create new span tag without a class name. `addClass('close')` will add class `close` to the span tag. It's another way to create new tag. Same to `<span class="close">`

Answer (score 0):

When the close function is outside of the div, it's trying to attach to existing `.close` elements and the element you are trying to attach to doesn't exist at that point in time. You need to do it inside because you need to have the `$newPet` element actually created before you can attach to it.

Comment: I think the the code $('.close').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }); will search the Dom then attach the remove function to it. However, you mean I need to attach it to the element before creating it, right?

Comment: correct. You need this to be run after the element is created, and in the top sample it runs before it is created

Answer (score 0):

`$('.close')` will search in the dom.

If you haven't appended your html, then it can't be found by `jQuery`